# What does the d represent in the equation of a plane ($ax+by+cz+d=0$)?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Look at the following problem:

> Consider the plane $\alpha$ defined by $x-2y+z+3=0$ and $A(0;0;2)$.
>
> Write an equation of the plane that is parallel to $\alpha$ and goes
>   through A.

My book states the solution is:

> The direction vector of $\alpha$ is $\vec{n}(1;-2;1)$ so the equation
>   of the plane is $x-2y+z+d=0$.
>
> A is in the plane, so:
>
> $$0 - 2 \cdot 0 + 2 +d = 0 \Leftrightarrow d = -2$$
>
> So the equation is: $x-2y+z-2=0$

What was the reasoning behind this? What does $d$ represent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plane $x-2y+z=0$ is a plane *that goes through the origin*, with normal vector $(1;-2;1)$.
The plane $x-2y+z+d=0$ has the same normal vector (it is parallel to the previous plane), but it may not go through the origin; changing $d$ amounts to sliding/translating the plane.

Comment: Just to clarify, that means sliding/translating the plane _d_ units along its normal vector (_A_, _B_, _C_)?

Comment: @brain56 For a scalar $c$, a translation of distance $c \sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}$ along the normal vector $(A,B,C)$ becomes $Ax+By+Cz = c(A^2+B^2+C^2)$.

Comment: sorry I don't think I still quite grasp that. What does the scalar *c* then mean geometrically? It looks like given the planar equation *Ax+By+Cz+D=0*, *-D* is equal to the dot product of the plane's normal with itself multiplied by a scalar *c*?

Comment: @brain56 see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1680465/234971

Answer (score 3):

The equation of a plane that goes through the origin can be written as $ax+by+cz=0$; notice that the origin $(0,0,0)$ satisfies this equation and hence belongs to the plane. Another of writing this equation is as follows:

$$\langle (a,b,c),(x,y,z)\rangle = 0$$

In other words, the vector $(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to the vector $(a,b,c)$.

Now, what happens if we introduce the parameter $d$ to this equation? We get

$$\langle (a,b,c),(x,y,z)\rangle = -d$$

Does that help? Probably not much, but what if you take some vector $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with $\langle (a,b,c),(x_0,y_0,z_0)\rangle=d$? Then, the equation becomes

\begin{align}
&\langle (a,b,c),(x,y,z)\rangle = -\langle (a,b,c),(x_0,y_0,z_0)\rangle\\
\iff &\langle (a,b,c),(x,y,z)+(x_0,y_0,z_0)\rangle=0\\
\iff &\langle (a,b,c),(x+x_0,y+y_0,z+z_0)\rangle=0
\end{align}

In other words, it's the set of vectors whose **translation by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$**  is perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$. This shows in a very direct way that this equation yields a translated version of our previous result.

Answer (score 1):

Another interpretation for $d$ is that you can rewrite the equation: $x-2y+z+d  = 0$ as $(1,-2,1)\cdot (x-0,y-0,z-2) = 0\implies x-2y+z-2 = 0\implies d = -2$. Thus we can generalize to general case: $\vec n=(a,b,c)$, and $A = (x_0,,y_0,z_0) \in \alpha\implies \vec n\cdot (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) = 0\implies (a,b,c)\cdot (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0 \implies a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0) = 0 \implies ax+by+cz - ax_0 - by_0 - cz_0 = 0\implies d = -ax_0-by_0-cz_0$

Answer (score 0):

A bit more general :

1) Consider a family of planes with normalized (length  = 1)     normal vectors $\vec{n} $.

2) Let one of the family members with normal  $\vec{n}$ pass through a point $\vec{r_0}$ .

The equation reads:

$(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0}) \cdot \vec{n}$ = $0$, or

$\vec{r} \cdot \vec{n} - \vec{r_0} \cdot \vec{n}$ = $0$.

The second term is

$d: = - \vec{r_0} \cdot \vec{n}$.

It is the (negative) projection of   $\vec{r_0}$, the point  the plane passes through, onto the normal, I.e. the (negative) length of the vector component of  $\vec{r_0}$ along $\vec{n}$.

Different family members, i.e. parallel planes, will have   $\alpha \vec{r_0}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, I.e. will pass through different points, where 
$\alpha \vec{r_0} \cdot \vec{n}$  is the (negative) length of the vector component along $\vec{n}$.