# What is D in Equation of a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

In a previous Quora post on this topic (https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-equation-ax-+-by-+-cz-d-define-a-plane), a respondent states that $D$ represents the distance from the origin to a plane. In a similar post on this site ([What does the d represent in the equation of a plane ($ax+by+cz+d=0$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327970/what-does-the-d-represent-in-the-equation-of-a-plane-axbyczd-0)), it was said that changing the value of $D$ results in translating/sliding the plane.

But since $D$ is a number and not a vector, how can we know in which direction this distance is measured? Is it just a case of positive $D$ resulting in translation to the right, along the $x$ (horizontal) axis, and negative $D$ resulting in translation to the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view $ax+bx+cz$ as the scalar product of vectors $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$, and the plane equation says that this scalar product is $-d$. So if $(a,b,c)$ is a vector of unit length, then our plane consists of all points on the plane perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$, translated by $-d$ units in the direction of vector $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Could you help me with this please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292324/show-the-quotient-space-of-a-finite-collection-of-disjoint-2-simplices-obtained? Thank you!